# Binding a jQuery event to code created in ASPX code-behind?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

For reasons out of my control I have both client-side JavaScript that builds up a row of an HTML table *and* similar code in the code-behind page that triggers after a button event.  On the client-side, there is an extra method that is called after the rows are created that unobtrusively and dynamically binds several `live` events to each input in the new row.

I need to get that same functionality from the row(s) created in the code-behind event handler.  I tried simply calling the same method via `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` but neither of them worked and no events trigger on the code-behind row (but they function as expected if I then add a client-side row).

Any idea how to handle this?  Should I call the client-side binding code elsewhere on the page rather than in the client-side creation method, so it will trigger on the code-behind?  Or is there another way to call it from the code-behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a startup script that parses the rows in bulk during page initialization as in:

```
$("table").find("tr").live(..);
```

So from the server-side, you need to render a script that processes the table in bulk, and then manage the client-side interactions in a singular fashion.

You should be able to render something out like this; please post some code if you can't.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `live` and the rows all share a common class then it shouldn't matter how they are added, the event should apply to them.  Simply run it once on page load and that's it.